# Do While loop works well with echo but loops only once with a function inside loop

Tags: php, mysql

This code is supposed to insert 100 rows into the DB.

Yet when I run it, it loops only once, inserts one row and stops.

I replaced the function call with :

```
echo $keywords[4].'<br>';
```

It works perfectly. with no probleb

What is missing so that it will insert all rows into DB?

what should I change q add so that the code will insert all rows in the file

Here is the loop code:

```
do{

        //Insert row content into array.
        $keywords = preg_split("#\<(.*?)\>#", $row);

        //Insert relevant data into DB


        add_data($keywords);

        }
    else{
            // If row is irrelevant - continue to next row
            continue;
        }

}while (strpos($row, 'Closed P/L') != true);
```

Here is the function

```
function add_data($keywords)
{
    global $db;

    $ticket =$keywords[2];
    $o_time = $keywords[4];
    $type = $keywords[6];
    $size = $keywords[8];
    $item = substr($keywords[10], 0,  -1);
    $o_price = $keywords[12]; 
    $s_l = $keywords[14];
    $t_p = $keywords[16];
    $c_time = $keywords[18];
    $c_price = $keywords[20];
    $profit = $keywords[28];

    try
    {
        $sql = "
            INSERT INTO `data`
            (ticket, o_time, type, size, item, o_price, s_l, t_p, c_time, c_price, profit)
            VALUES
            (:ticket, :o_time, :type, :size, :item, :o_price, :s_l, :t_p, :c_time, :c_price, :profit)"; 


        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam('ticket', $ticket, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam('o_time', $o_time, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam('type', $type, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam('size', $size, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam('item', $item, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam('o_price', $o_price, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam('s_l', $s_l, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam('t_p', $t_p, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam('c_time', $c_time, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam('c_price', $c_price, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam('profit', $profit, PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $stmt->execute();

        //return true;  
    }
    catch(Exception $e)


    {
       return false;
       echo 'something is wrong. Here is the system\'s message:<br>'.$e;
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably from the manual `Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function.` is relevant here. If not please provide sample data so the code can be run.

Comment: It looks like you're missing an `if` condition somewhere

Comment: How do you know your function doesn't raise an exception? ico an exception you return with the value false. The echo line isn't executed. And  you're not doing anything with the returned value.

Comment: regardless of error this is a very inefficient approach, you dont need to prepare ever time, you prepare just once.